# SimpleCov 0% coverage

Tags: ruby, rubygems, code-coverage

I'm working on a small gem and included [simplecov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) to `spec_helper.rb` two lines:

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start
```

When I run the rspec test, the simplecov seems started correctly but the report is not:

```
Finished in 0.00214 seconds
8 examples, 0 failures

Coverage report generated for /home/...... 
spec to /home/megas/Work/calc/coverage. 0 / 0 LOC (0.0%) covered.
```

What might be a problem and how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Also make sure to enable simplecov (a.k.a. `SimpleCov.start`) at the **very** beginning of your file; especially before you require your code.

Comment: This was my issue; thank you. Someone else pointed out a helpful way to diagnose: Add a `puts` debug message to the top of an app/model file, and another one in `spec_helper.rb` right next to your `SimpleCov.start` -- if you see the model debug output before the SimpleCov debug output, you know your model is getting loaded before SimpleCov.

Comment: Very important - `SimpleCov.start` must go BEFORE your `require` the code to be tested.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same symptoms. My problem was that in my test file:

```rb
#spec/oneclass_spec.rb
require 'oneclass'
require 'spec_helper'

...Rest of the test file
```

And I needed to change the order of the `require`s to:

```rb
#spec/oneclass_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
require 'oneclass'

...Rest of the test file
```

Hope this helps someone, I was going crazy...

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. For some reason, some modules were reported with 0% of coverage. After some investigation, I found that one of the initialisers required a controller, which caused modules to be loaded before Simplecov. What I did I moved Simplecov to initialiser:

```rb
# config/initializers/_coverage_rspec.rb

if Rails.env.test?
  require 'simplecov'
  SimpleCov.start 'rails'
end
```

If you're using spring, remember to turn it off when you run tests with coverage. In another case, the complete application code will be loaded before SimpleCov and report 0% coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case the above two answers didn't work (as in my case) a user on simplecov's github issues page suggested this, which worked for me.

Add this after you require simplecov-

```
module SimpleCov::Configuration
  def clean_filters
    @filters = []
  end
end

SimpleCov.configure do
  clean_filters
  load_adapter 'test_frameworks'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If one of the above didn't work.

verify that in test.rb:

```
config.eager_load = false
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was spring - I had to create a `config/spring.rb` with the following:

```
if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'test'
  require 'simplecov'
  SimpleCov.start
end
```

as documented [here](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov#want-to-use-spring-with-simplecov).

Answer (score 0):

I am running scripts from the command line and I found the solution was simply to put an **exit** at the end of my script. Doh!

Alternatively, the following also works

```
SimpleCov.at_exit do
  SimpleCov.result.format!
end
```